# Cassandra Bulk Load Data

Tags: cassandra

I have a system that generate 100,000 rows/s and size of each row is 1KB and want to use Cassandra for database.
I get data from Apache Kafka and then should insert it into database.
What is the best way for load this volume of data into Cassandra ?

Comment: Split the data into batches. Preferably batches of size 1000 and write the data to cassandra db.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect is designed for this. On this page you will find a list of connectors including a Cassandra sink connectors https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Comment: I get CSV messages from kafka. it seems connectors work with avro format. Am I true ?

Comment: Not sure about CSV messages, but json is doable in addition to avro:
http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/cassandra-sink.html#legacy-topics-plain-text-payload-with-a-json-string

Honestly it's probably easier to write something like a streams application to transform your CSV into json or avro and then write it out to a new topic that can be pulled in to Cassandra. You could also write your own converter for CSV or try the StringConverter that ships with Kafka. Not sure how well this will work with Cassandra, but any of these options are easier than writing your own full app.

Comment: Data conversion from CSV to JSON or AVRO can be easily implemented in a small Apache CAMEL module. It supports Kafka connections so you can read from Kafka, convert and write back to Kafka as mentioned by @dawsaw. You can also scale it as needed.